# Git project in eclipse disappeared from workspace after a pull

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

My Java Project disappeared from the Project Explorer after I performed the following actions with egit:

- **Commit**  Successfully performed
- **Push to upstream** Didn't succeed (not sure about the reason but I think it was because a pull was required first)
- **Pull** Egit says the project merged successfully

After I closed the window containing the info on the merge (to which I didn't really pay attention since the repo handles two different projects and the updates were on the one I-m not working on) the project disappeared from the Project Explorer. Any idea why this happened? I'm not looking for a solution to re-import the project but for a reason that explains this behavior.

Comment: Maybe the .project disappeared?

Comment: Indeed it did, but I'm not 100% sure I ever pushed it to the repo...

Comment: may i know, How many members are working in your project?

Comment: At the moment the active users are 2/3

Answer (score 2):

In some cases we get this type of problems, i will explain the points in steps wise

- If two persons works on the project **personA**, **personB**.
- If **personB** adds new files, those files path saves in our project **binary file**. so **personsB**
  done **Commit** and **pushed** the code.
- and **personA** also added new files, here also same way files path saves in our project **binary file** and performed **commit** operation and **pulled** the code which on remote side.
- **Here the situation arise** when **personA** pulls the code conflicts arise in the **binary file**. in this case **project disappears from the Project Explorer**.

i faced this type of problem before. i merged both files not worked.

### Solution for the above problem

Whenever if we perform pull operation and get conflicts in **binary file**. I follow the below procedure

- In this case i use this command`git checkout --ours binaryfilenamewithpath`

  `git checkout --ours filename`   ->  it keeps your local file without adding others changes
- by this we can avoid **project disappeared from the Project Explorer** cases. Here you get **personBs** files but files links can not add to the **binary file**.
- so manually we have to those files into our project for linking purpose.
- then you can commit the your project.

I prefer this way to resolve this type of problems. If you have any doubts please ask me.

### Solution for your problem

- Execute `git log` command it will show your previous commits information with their ids
- `git reset --hard commitid(c14809fa)` it will make your local code and local history
  be just like it was at that commit.
- pull your code using `git pull origin branchname`
- if you get conflict in **binaryfile**, then **your project disappear from eclipse workspace**. use this command `git checkout --ours binaryfilewithpath` to avoid that.
- if you want to add files to your project and resolve conflicts in other files.
- then commit your code by using `git commit -a -m 'your commit message'`

Comment: added solution for your problem check once.

Comment: this is ok, but remember I've been using egit, so no command line. And no conflicts were shown btw

Comment: i donot know much about egit, but you can install git for your operating system and you can use these commands.